# Swiping between Fragment Activites using FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter

I created two separate Fragment Activities that were linked by a button but I have recently decided that I wanted to swipe between them. I was wanting to use FragmentPagerAdapter and  was wondering if FragmentPagerAdapter treated Fragment Activities like Fragments or if there was a way to make it so. I'm not sure what I should return in the getItem method within the FragmentPagerAdpater. The Fragment activites will end up being fairly complex so I want to avoid recreating it all within a fragment.

Comment: You only want the `SwipeView` between two fragments but without tabs. is it